# Labels for ANgular2 highcharts

Tags: highcharts, angular2-template, angular2-highcharts

Hello,

I am working on angular2 highcharts,on mouse over only charts displaying data labels.But i need to display the labels always not particularly on mouse over like we display in jquery highcharts(https://www.highcharts.com/demo/pie-basic).

Below is angular-highchart working code

```
  export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor() {
        this.options = {
        title: { text: 'simple chart' },
        series: [{
            data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2],
        }]
        };
    }
   options: Object;

   ngOnInit(): void {  }
 }
```

please any help.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Anyone understands my question??

Comment: Do you mean **tooltip** instead of  **data labels**? This doc page explains what the tooltip is: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/tooltip